# Array.filter() does not filter element despite function returning false

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to use the filter function to remove an element from an array. This is in Typescript/Angular6 but I think this snippet applies to JS in general.

Below code does not seem to filter out the element I want despite the filter function returning `false` for that element. At least I think it returns `false` as the comparison evaluates to false (see output).

The verbose manual function with `Array.splice()` does do its job. What am I not seeing?

```
  public deleteAltChar() {
    console.log(this.char.altchars);
    this.charService.deleteAltChar(this.altChar, this.char)
      .subscribe(data => {
        // THIS DOES NOT WORK
        this.char.altchars.filter(ac => {
            console.log(ac);
            console.log(this.altChar);
            console.log(this.altChar != ac);
            return ac != this.altChar;
        });
        console.log(this.char.altchars);
        // THIS DOES WORK
        // this.char.altchars.forEach(ac => {
        //  if (ac == this.altChar) {
        //      this.char.altchars.splice(this.char.altchars.indexOf(ac), 1);
        //  }
        // });
      });
  }
```

output from first part:

```
Array[0: Object { id: 37 }]
Object { id: 37 }
Object { id: 37 }
false
Array[0: Object { id: 37 }]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array.filter returns a new array with the filtered values, it doesn't change the instance it's invoked on, check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

So you would wanna do something like that

```
this.char.altchars = this.char.altchars.filter(ac => ac != this.altChar);
```

Comment: OH. Dang. So it should be `this.char.altchars = this.char.altchars.filter(...)` ?

Answer (score 1):

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns a new array, thus you need assign result of filter to some variable.

```
this.char.altchars = this.char.altchars.filter(ac => {
     console.log(ac);
     console.log(this.altChar);
     console.log(this.altChar != ac);
     return ac != this.altChar;
});
```